# How can I compare addresses with the 'eq' operator in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I'm using Mongo with Kotlin and I'm looking to compare an address category.

In this case, I have three addresses:

MAIN, DELIVERY & BILLING

So, if an address is MAIN I want to compare it with `AddressCategory.MAIN`, if not then with another address category and so on.

I'm quite a beginner in Kotlin, I tried to use the logical and ternary operators to make this comparison, but I couldn't.

```
   eq(Address::category, AddressCategory.MAIN.toString()) ,
                         eq(Address::category, AddressCategory.DELIVERY.toString()),
                         eq(Address::category, AddressCategory.BILLING.toString())
```

The comparison would be like this, if the MAIN address does not exist I will do the comparison by DELIVERY, if it does not exist, I do it by BILLING, always with this order of precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `when` to do that. Something like:

```
when(Address::category) {
    is AddressCategory.MAIN -> AddressCategory.MAIN.toString()
    is AddressCategory.DELIVERY -> AddressCategory.DELIVERY.toString()
    is AddressCategory.BILLING -> AddressCategory.BILLING.toString()
}
```

You will need to fill in the gaps since I don't have a complete understanding of that you are trying to accomplish but this can give you an idea of how you can try to implement this